# access to custom cloudwatch metrics using lambda+boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, boto, amazon-lambda

I have a custom metrics, and I can get data from bash:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace System/Detail/Linux \
--metric-name LoadAverage1Min --start-time 2017-01-04T00:00:00 \
--end-time 2017-01-04T02:00:00 --period 60 --statistics Average \
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-03d55dba88912f054
{
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-04T00:33:00Z",
            "Average": 0.0,
            "Unit": "Count"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-04T01:44:00Z",
            "Average": 0.0,
... etc...
```

But it does not work for lambda. The question is: **how to get data for custom metrics?**

I'm trying to do the sane using lambda and boto3 (sorry, beginner in Python):

```
import boto3
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
cw = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
    # all running EC2 instances.
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running']
        }
    ]

    #filter the instances
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    #locate all running instances
    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    dnow = datetime.now()

    for instance in instances:
        inst_name = [tag['Value'] for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Name'][0]
        if inst_name != 'instances-name-i-need':
            continue

        response = cw.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='System/Detail/Linux',
            MetricName='LoadAverage1Min',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                    'Name': 'InstanceId',
                    'Value': 'instance.id'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=dnow+timedelta(hours=-15),
            EndTime=dnow,
            Period=300,
            Statistics=['Average']
        )
        print response
```

But when I run the function via lambda test I receive empty responses only:

```
{u'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '98ee...6ba', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '98ee...6ba', 'date': 'Thu, 05 Jan 2017 22:52:12 GMT', 'content-length': '338', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}, u'Label': 'LoadAverage1Min'}
{u'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '98f4...a01', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '98f4...a01', 'date': 'Thu, 05 Jan 2017 22:52:13 GMT', 'content-length': '338', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}, u'Label': 'LoadAverage1Min'}
{u'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '98f8...764', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '98f8...764', 'date': 'Thu, 05 Jan 2017 22:52:13 GMT', 'content-length': '338', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}, u'Label': 'LoadAverage1Min'}
```

However I was able to get data from AWS namespace with

```
response = cw.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/S3',MetricName='BucketSizeBytes',
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=2) ,
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(), Period=86400,
    Statistics=['Average'], Unit='Bytes',
    Dimensions=[
        {'Name': 'BucketName', 'Value': 'bucket-name'},
        {u'Name': 'StorageType', u'Value': 'StandardStorage'}
    ]
)
```

The data for the metrics does exist:
[image]

so, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stupid error:

```
'Value': 'instance.id'
```

should be

```
'Value': instance.id
```

because `instance.id` is a variable.